# Efficient use of python objects to iterate over a large set of data calling python functions

Tags: c++, python

My application has generated a large (>4gb) of data and I need to iterate over it calling a python function on every data element.

My data will be broken down into "rows" and I'll be defining several python variables (objecs) which will reference this data. Ideally these objects would be in native form, i.e. my data will have doubles, integers and arrays of char etc, i.e.

```
struct DataRow
{
    char key[ 32 ];
    double value;
    int source;
};
DataRow *rows = new DataRow[ 40000000 ];
```

I've read a little on the PyBuffer object which can "wrap" an area of memory and I'd assumed that I'd be able to construct 3 of these to "point" to the first row of data (key, value, source) and then construct a tuple and call PyObject_CallObject() on a code object I'd prepared earlier.

```
PyObject *keyBuffer = PyBuffer_FromMemory( rows[ 0 ].key, 32 );
PyObject *valueBuffer = PyBuffer_FromMemory( &rows[ 0 ].value, sizeof( double ) );
PyObject *sourceBuffer = PyBuffer_FromMemory( &rows[ 0 ].source, sizeof( int ) );
```

However, this approach seems to present several issues..

1. How do I advance the pointer held by the PyBuffer objects to point to the next row.
2. How do I dererence the double and int buffers to use thier values inside the python script

I'm sure that this must be possible. If it's not then it may be that using python script across all the rows may be too slow given the amount of PyObjects I'd have to construct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do any operations on the data, there is no escaping having to create a large number of python objects.  The chars, double, and int need to become immutable PyString, PyFloat, and PyInt objects respectively.

Since you are already writing C, you might as well create an iterator that returns a series of key/value/source tuples.

What is nice about this approach is that you can reuse the objects between successive calls as long as no references were kept to those objects.  This can save you from allocations and frees for each object.  For an example of how to do this, see the source for itertools.izip at  http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Modules/itertoolsmodule.c#l3541 .  I believe this approach will give you the efficiency you seek without much effort (just hack-up the izip code to meet your needs).

Comment: I've had a look at the example code and I'm not quite sure where you are reusing the objects created inside the tuple. It looks like you're creating a new item, extracting the existing item from the tuple, replacing the existing item with the new item and then decrementing the old item. This would result in new objects per "iteration". How would you go about "reusing" the objects rather than replacing as you appear to do.

Comment: @ScaryAardvark In the branch for ``Py_REFCNT(result) == 1)``, the *result* tuple is re-used.  You can try going a step further to reuse each of the int/float/str within the tuple using the same technique.